# how to do this conversion?

Tags: c#

```
string mvi = Moneys.GetValue(8) as string;
if (mvi == null)
     // I am getting exception Here if its null?
     money.Currency= Convert.ToDecimal("");
else
     // Currency is Decimal
     money.Currency= Convert.ToDecimal(mvi);
// I am getting exception Here if its null?
money.Currency= Convert.ToDecimal("");
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want null and empty to count as zero while gibberish throws an exception?

Comment: I'll take that as a yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version of Anthony Pegram's answer:

```
string mvi = Moneys.GetValue(8) as string;
money.Currency = 0M;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvi))
   if (!Decimal.TryParse(mvi, out money.Currency))
     throw new FormatException("mvi");
```

On the whole, it looks quite a bit like the one Alex made, only it treats empty as zero and shows more error-handling.

Answer (score 4):

Empty string is not convertible to decimal. You could perform a check like this

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mvi))
{
   money.Currency = 0M;
}
else 
{
   decimal temp = 0M;
   if (decimal.TryParse(mvi, out temp))
   {
        money.Currency = temp;
   }
   else 
   {
       // you have an invalid input, handle
   }
}
```

Comment: This is correct but a bit long.  I've put together a more compact version as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDecimal()`:

```
decimal theValue;
string mvi = Moneys.GetValue(8) as string;
Decimal.TryParse( mvi, out theValue );
```

alternatively, you can use the null coallescing operator to handle nulls preemtively:

```
var theValue = Convert.ToDecimal( mvi ?? "0" );
```

In both cases, however, you have to decide what to do if the value coming in is not a valid decimal.

Comment: I think he actually wants both empty and null to count as zero.

Comment: The second example counts null as zero, but fails on empty.  The first counts both empty and null as zero, but also counts gibberish as zero.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65.aspx

I think you want Convert.ToDecimal("0.0"); otherwise you get a EDIT: ArgumentNullException